# Retrieving single pair [Key/Value] from hashtable during each retrial of hashtable.

Tags: generics, hashmap, hashtable

I want to retrieve single String from hashtable.

Here, In my code the Hashtable key is returning some id [ex 1234] and value is returning some url [ex ww.abc.com/] and at the last step I am appending this id to the url.

I want my function to return that complete url [Appended one ], as with each iteration of that hashtable the key and value would be different. so that url would also be different.
I want this function to retrieve URL (Key-Value pair) with each table iteration.

```
public String readFromHashtable(Hashtable<String, String> recruiter){

            String url=null;        
            try{                
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = recruiter.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) 
                    {
                        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
                        String key = pair.getKey();
                        String value = pair.getValue();
                        url =new StringBuffer(value).append(key).toString();
                        System.out.println(url);
                    }        
                }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return url;
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to return url each time"? Each time what? When you call your method, it can only return a single URL. It sounds like you might want to implement an iterator...

Comment: See, the key is returning some id ex 1234 and value is returning some url ex ww.abc.com/ and at the last step I am appending this id to the url and  I want my function to return that complete url as with each iteration of that hashtable the key and value would be different. so that url would also be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but I *suspect* you want to return an `Iterable<String>` from your method rather than a single string. For example:

```
// No need to tie ourselves to Hashtable...
public static Iterable<String> readFromMap(final Map<String, String> map) {
    return new Iterable<String>() {
        @Override public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                private final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator
                    = map.entrySet().iterator();

                @Override public void remove() {
                    iterator.remove();
                }

                @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterator.hasNext();
                }

                @Override public String next() {
                    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
                    return entry.getValue() + entry.getKey();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

This looks like a lot of code, but really it's just wrapping the iterator returned by `Map.entrySet().iterator()` so that it can transform each entry. Another option would be to use [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Something like:

```
// No need to tie ourselves to Hashtable...
public static Iterable<String> readFromMap(final Map<String, String> map) {
    return Iterables.transform(map.entrySet(),
        new Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override public String apply(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
                return entry.getValue() + entry.getKey();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: See, the hashtable key is returning some id [ex 1234] and value is returning some url [ex ww.abc.com/] and at the last step I am appending this id to the url. Now, I want my function to return that complete url as with each iteration of that hashtable the key and value would be different. so that url would also be different.

Comment: @Yougandhara: I assume by the fact that you've accepted my answer that this *was* what you were looking for - but please think about how you could have asked the question more clearly to start with. If you've got a method that you call many times, with a potentially different map each time, it's hard to see how you would expect it to maintain state about the map between each call.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind regarding clarity of the question. But the only concern I have is how to return a string while iterating through hashtable. Now, I used arraylist.. I stored data from hashmap into Arraylist and I am iterating though Arraylist, but is there any way we can return string while iterating through hashtable only.

Comment: @Yougandhara: I don't understand what you mean. You should just iterate over the result of calling the method I've provided - that will give you the relevant results.